# Entropy increase when conditioning

Tags: probability, statistics, information-theory, entropy

I know that a property of conditional entropy is that it cannot increase the entropy of the conditioning variable, however it seems to happen for me in the following example. Can anyone help me out where I am wrong?

Assume two discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$. The pmf of $X$ is $p_X(x) = 1/8$.

The entropy of $X$ must then be (assuming $\log = \log_2$), $$H(X) = -\sum_xp(x)\log(p(x)) = \log(8)  = 3$$
We assume that $y \in \{1,2\} $ and $p_Y(y) = 1/2$ and $p_{XY}(x|y) = 1/4$.

The conditional entropy is then

\begin{align*}
H(X|Y) &= -\sum_yp(y) \sum_x p(x|y) \log(p(x|y))\\
 &= -\left(2\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2} \cdot \left(8 \cdot \frac{1}{4} \cdot \log\left( \frac{1}{4}\right)\right)\right)\right)\\
 &= 4
\end{align*}

Which then clearly is wrong. Intuitively, I would assume that it would be $2$ rather than $4$.

Comment: Firstly the statement $p_X(x) = 1/8$ is unclear. I am assuming it means $X$ can take one of $8$ distinct values, each with an equal probability. Similarly for $y$. When you do $p_{X|Y}$, I am assuming, given the value of $y$, $x$ can now assume only $4$ of the $8$ values, again equally likely, giving probability of $1/4$. Assuming all of this, in the expression $H(X|Y)$, instead of $8$, you should have $4$ since after conditioning $X$ can only assume $4$ distinct values. That should solve your problem. If I have misunderstood anything, please edit the problem to clarify those points.

Comment: Thanks @sudeep5221.

Comment: @sn3jd3r: If the comment answered your question, you could post what you understood as an answer and accept it so that the question doesn't remain unanswered.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm in the same situation